# Qual é a diferença entre "mau" e "mal"?

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Qual é a diferença entre *mau* e *mal?*

Em cada caso abaixo, qual é a forma apropriada para o uso de cada um?

> Lobo (mau|mal)
>
> Falou (mau|mal)
>
> Isso soou muito (mau|mal)

Comment: Podes explicar na pergunta o porquê da confusão entre mal e mau?

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso tem haver com a forma em como é pronunciada, pelos brasileiros, as palavra terminadas em "al". Eu no Brasil sou chamado de Amarau!

Comment: Eu sei @ramaral, mas essa informação devia estar na pergunta.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O “mau” é o contrário de “bom”, e é um adjetivo.

O “mal” é o contrário de “bem”, e é um advérbio.

Comment: Pode ser idiota, mas para gravar qual é o contrário de qual eu penso na palavra "LE" do Espanhol, e no jogo "UO" (ultima online) :) Assim nunca erro na hora de escrever.

Comment: eu só agora percebi a confusão entre mal e mau, é porque ai a fonia das palavras é a mesma, aqui não.

Comment: @JorgeB. e é justamente essa resposta que eu quero melhorar após a aprender mais sobre fonemas, explicando que no Brasil o som é igual, mas em Portugal são diferentes :)

Comment: Eu nunca mais esqueci a diferença quando me ensinaram a diferenciar isso pelas "curvas" das letras. Vendo [essa imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZMgJ.jpg) fica bem simples de "decorar".

Comment: @RafaelTavares ótimo mapa mental, só tem que lembrar de enxergar as letras em maiúsculo rs

Answer (score 9):

Nos casos que você citou, as formas apropriadas são:

> Lobo mau
>
> falou mal
>
> Isso soou muito mal

A diferença é: "mau" é adjetivo e qualifica somente substantivos, como "Lobo", no seu exemplo. "Mal" é advérbio e, como tal, pode qualificar verbos ("falar" e "soar", nos seus exemplos), mas também adjetivos, como em "mal arrumado".

Por fim, lembre-se que a palavra "mal" também pode ser um substantivo, dependendo do contexto. "Do mal ficam as mágoas na lembranca".

Answer (score 1):

"Mau", como todo mundo já disse, é o antônimo de "bom". É também o masculino de "má":

> O lobo mau
>
> A loba má

E o plural de "mau" é "maus":

> Os maus alunos foram reprovados.

"Mal", como também já foi dito e repetido, é o contrário de "bem" - tanto como advérbio:

> Ele se expressou mal.
>
> Ele se expressou bem.

como quanto substantivo:

> A eterna luta do bem contra o mal.

Exceto, claro, nos casos em que não tem antônimo:

> Mal de Hansen

E "mal" não tem forma feminina. Quando advérbio, não tem gênero; quando substantivo, é sempre masculino:

> *A eterna luta da "benha" contra a "mala"...

E, finalmente, o plural do substantivo "mal" é "males" (advérbios também não têm plural):

> Há males que vêm para o bem.