# Equivalent expression for “waking up on the wrong side of the bed” in Portuguese

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

The expression "waking up on the wrong side of the bed" means
*to feel irritated; to be in a bad mood; to have a bad day from the start; to wake up in a bad mood*.

Does there exist an equivalent expression in Portuguese (Europe/Brazilian)?

---

A expressão "waking up on the wrong side of the bed" significa: 
*sentir-se irratado; estar de mau humor; ter começado o dia mal; acordar de mau humor*.

Existe alguma expressão equivalente em português?

Comment: Guilherme é [**mau** e não mal](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mau-e-mal).

Comment: @JorgeB. Corrigido, foi na pressa kk

Answer (score 9):

At least in Brazil we have "Acordar com o pé esquerdo" ("Got out of the bed with the left foot"). There's also "Acordar da pá virada" (this one is really hard to translate to English, but it goes something like "Woke up with my shovel turned").

The thing is that both "pé esquerdo" and "pá virada" can mean "bad mood" even outside of those expressions, so they're not *specific* to waking up.

---

Temos no Brazil a expressão "Acordar com o pé esquedo". Há também "Acordar da pá virada". Mas tanto "pé esquerdo" quanto "pá virada" podem significar "mau humor" fora dessas expressões, então elas não estão restritas à essas situações.

Comment: "da pá virada" não significa que foi botado da pá para o chão?

Comment: “da pá virada” ou, como preferem os antigos, “do apá virado” não quer dizer quando a pessoa tem comportamento buliçoso, brincalhão, amalucado, assanhado, ousado, imprevisível, impetuoso? http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/da-pa-virada-ou-do-apa-virado.jhtm

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Talvez seja uma adaptação da minha região (Espírito Santo). "Pá virada" também significa agitado, impetuoso, etc., lá e o significado de "mau humor" pode ter derivado daí

Answer (score 8):

Em Portugal usamos muito a expressão:

> Acordar com os pés de fora

---

In Portugal one would say:

> Waking up with their feet out of bed.

Answer (score 6):

In Brazil there is "Levantar com o pé esquerdo" (to get up on the left foot).

Comment: Também se usa em Portugal essa.

Comment: @JorgeB. Mas com o pronome: "Levantar-se com o pé esquerdo"

Answer (score 3):

Here:

> Dormiu com a bunda fora da coberta.

But it can seem rude in some regions.

Comment: Sério? ahahahahahahahah

Comment: Sim... apsokaspoaks principalmente pro ser um lugar bem frio

Comment: @JorgeB. Nunca ouvi essa. Será que é algo regional?

Comment: @LucasMotta és de onde?

Comment: @JorgeB. Farroupilha, estado do Rio Grande do Sul - Brazil, na Serra Gaúcha.

Comment: @LucasMotta então essa deve ser Regional, por ai ser mais frio. Certo?

Comment: @JorgeB. comparado com a maior parte do Brasil, sim, é muito frio, ainda mais agora que estamos em pleno inverno.

Comment: Fui pesquisar e não achei, então pesquisei Dormiu com a bunda descoberta e encontrei isto http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/dormiu%20com%20a%20bunda%20descoberta/ parece que é usado, só nunca ouvi.

Comment: Justamente, até porque pode parecer grosseiro

Comment: Até vou colocar isso na resposta.

Comment: Nessa mesma linha, mas sem o problema de parecer rude, tem o *dormiu de calça jeans*.